# How to check USB stick which has invalid file?

Tags: usb

I am using a FAT formatted USB stick to listen to music in my car radio. Upon inserting the stick the radio tells me that there is a invalid file on the stick, but starts to play (always the same track). I can navigate through the folders and files, select music as I want, but the 'invalid file' issue bugs me.

I did a `dosfsck` on the entire stick from a Ubuntu computer

```
sudo dosfsck -w -r -l -a -v -t /dev/sdc1
```

but it came back negative. Also a visual inspection of the many many files did not show anything suspicuous (although I cannot rule out to have overlooked something).

So is there anything else to find the offending file(s)?

Comment: Depending on your car radio, the problem might be an/some invalid character/s in the name/s of the songs, or the number of characters of a song is larger than your radio can support

Comment: Yes, but is there a command line too to check that? Maybe I write something myself...

Comment: You can write something, but you need to know what you are looking for. I suggest you search after the car radio's model and find out what should you search for.

Comment: Not easy at all...

Comment: You could rename every file so it contains first `x` letters of the name of the artist and first `y` letters of the name of the song.